# EFI deleted pls help

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, bios

I accidentally deleted efi while trying to delete windows dualboot thing and restarted.I am stuck at the bios menu I think I’m new to disk partition management. What do I do?

Comment: Use gparted and create a new FAT32 partition with boot,esp flags. The run Boot-Repair to totally reinstall grub, default may not be that, and then you have to use Boot-Repair's advanced mode. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  Gparted is on Ubuntu live installer or can be downloaded as its own live system. https://gparted.org/faq.php

Comment: My computer is stuck on the boot screen saying I have no os installed or smth.

Comment: You need to use UEFI boot key on system to boot Ubuntu live installer. Unless you manually select the USB flash drive, it will default boot or try to boot from missing ESP.

Comment: So I would have to reinstall Ubuntu with a flash drive?

Comment: Is there anyway to keep the existing file system?

Comment: You don't have to re-install it. You need to boot from a LiveUSB and fix it.

Comment: how do i fix it once I have booted from a LiveUSB?

Answer (score 0):

Boot from an Ubuntu live USB, select *Try Ubuntu*, and use the built-in GParted partition editor to create a new 500MB EFI System partition formatted as FAT32 at the start of the disk manually. Then run the Ubuntu installer again. If the Ubuntu installation is successful, the Ubuntu installer will run all the way through the installation including installing the grub bootloader.